# Return NOW if it's the current hour

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a column with empty values if it's not the current hour, else return NOW.

I tried this:

```
CurrentHour = IF(Datatime_long[Date] = YEAR(TODAY()) && Datatime_long[Time] = HOUR(NOW()), "NOW","")
```

Could somebody spot the mistake or is there another way to tackle this ?

Data looks like this and sample output is CurrentHour with all empty values
[image]

Comment: Do you get an error or incorrect output? Can you share your sample dataset?

Comment: I am guessing your Datetime_long[Date] has more than just YEAR? so you might want to use YEAR on the other side of the comparison aswell, same thing for the [Time] column, use HOUR on the column side aswell.

Comment: I added how data looks like and output

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to use DATEDIFF: using it with HOUR parameter will return zero only if we are in the current hour.

This column should work:

```
ThisHour = IF(DATEDIFF(DateTable[Datetime], NOW(), HOUR) = 0, NOW(), BLANK())
```